# Uninstall puppet-agent silently using powershell failed

Tags: powershell, puppet, silent-installer

i tried to uninstall puppet-agent-x64 silently used this command:

```
$registryPath = Get-ChildItem -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall", "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall" | Get-ItemProperty | Where-Object {
    $_.displayName -eq "Puppet Agent (64-bit)" 
} | Select-Object -Property UninstallString

$uninstall = $registryPath.UninstallString

& cmd /c $uninstall /qn /norestart
```

and one can still finding the program under appwiz.cpl

Any hence please!

Comment: Check `$LASTEXITCODE` afterwards; most console applications indicate failure via a non-zero value.

Comment: Thanks alot, the code above worked very fine, i executed it before in "powershell ISE" but i already checked it in "powershell" and was puppet-agent-x64 completely removed